# Protection against instant deletion of a question which gets an answer

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I've recently answered a question which got deleted in a few minutes after I posted my answer (and as result, my answer and all comments made by others were removed as well).

Although I enjoyed thinking about the question which was nice (it was open for a day before my answer), I somehow feel exploited by such behavior from the question owner and do not think it is in the spirit of this community by any means (it was mentioned that the question was asked by a professor for a test).

Are there any policies at Stack Exchange for such occasions?

Comment: "t was mentioned that the question was asked by a professor for a test" Seems par for the course for someone cheating on a test ;).

Comment: I'd go with flagging the answer (if you can access it) for moderator attention explaining the case, or flag another of your post, a moderator will be able to find the deleted one. A question author is not supposed to delete his/her question once answered as a general rule.

Comment: thanks for all the replies, I'll proceed with the suggestions.

Comment: Yeah.. best to just not answer such questions.  Such OP's don't care about cheating on tests, they only care about getting their answer to copy out.  They don't care about SO aims and policy, and certainly don't give a PHP about you:(

Comment: well, it's hard to predict such behavior in advance. Many problems are from tests, homework, assignments, etc.  Besides the question was nice and I enjoyed thinking about it. Anyway, it has been recovered now by moderators.

Comment: @Hayk 'been recovered now by moderators'  I hope you get some rep for your efforts:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to flag it, but if it is not accessible, then ask about it on your per-site Meta.

Either way I think the outcome you should seek is that the question be undeleted by a moderator.

The above assumes that the question was self-deleted by its asker (and not by a moderator).